# why could not finish iOS purchase transaction when using in app purchase in flutter

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

Now I am develop in app purchase using this [lib](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) in flutter. After verify the receipt on the server side, I want to finish the purchase workflow. This is my code in flutter client side:

```
void _listenToPurchaseUpdated(List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList, Context<PayState> ctx) {
  purchaseDetailsList.forEach((PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) async {
    if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.pending) {
      RestLog.logger("PurchaseStatus pending..." + ctx.state.payModel.isAvailable.toString());
      _showPendingUI(ctx);
    } else {
      if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.error) {
        RestLog.logger("PurchaseStatus error");
        _handleError(purchaseDetails.error!, ctx);
      } else if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.restored) {
        RestLog.logger("purchase successful trigger verify");
        PayVerifyModel payVerifyModel = PayVerifyModel(orderId: purchaseDetails.purchaseID, receipt: purchaseDetails.verificationData.serverVerificationData);
        int result = await Pay.verifyUserPay(payVerifyModel);
        if(result == 0){
          RestLog.logger("verify success:" + result.toString());
          await InAppPurchase.instance.completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
        }else{
          RestLog.logger("verify failed:" + result.toString());
        }
      }else if(purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased ){
        RestLog.logger("purchaseDetails purchased:" + purchaseDetails.productID);
      }
      if (purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase) {
        await InAppPurchase.instance.completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

after verify success, I am using this code to finish the purchase:

```
  await InAppPurchase.instance.completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
```

but it seems did not work. It still runs in verify workflow the next time enter the purchase page, am I missing something? what should I do to make it work? This function `InAppPurchase.instance.completePurchase` did not return any status so I could not if it execute success.

I have tried to wrap a try catch in the outer level if the `InAppPurchase.instance.completePurchase(purchaseDetails)` code run into issue.But there is no error output.

I just do not known the transaction of purchase finished success. what should I do to get the result of complete transaction?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Have you got any solution? @Dolphin

Comment: Yes,I have solved this problem, I check my code and find in the initial function, I invoke the restore workflow, remove the function from initial function should fix it. The plugin could works fine, be patient and check your code. I could not debbug in emulator and send log to server side to see the code workflow. hope this help you!!!@RushabhShah you could see the code from here, my app is open source:https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/cruise-open

Comment: Thanks! But I think my issue is different. Could you please look into https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/88000
@Dolphin

Comment: I sometimes facing the same problem as you, but I did not have time to check it. The developer have told it just in sandbox env. Maybe in production this problem disappear? I am not sure.@RushabhShah